# SQL Trigger Not Working For updating same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a trigger for after insert

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateClientNumber]
ON  [dbo].[APP_Clients]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Count bigint

DECLARE @ClientNumber nchar(15)

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[APP_Clients]

IF @Count = 0
BEGIN

    SET @ClientNumber = CONVERT(nchar(4), YEAR(GETDATE())) + '01' + '0001'

    UPDATE [dbo].[APP_Clients]
    SET [ClientNumber] = @ClientNumber
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[APP_Clients] j ON i.ID = j.ID 

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SELECT @ClientNumber = MAX(SUBSTRING([ClientNumber], 7, len([ClientNumber]) - 0))
    FROM [dbo].[APP_Clients]
    WHERE (SUBSTRING([ClientNumber], 1, len([ClientNumber]) - 6) = YEAR(GETDATE()))

    SET @ClientNumber = CONVERT(bigint, @ClientNumber) + 1

    SET @ClientNumber = CONVERT(nchar(4), YEAR(GETDATE())) + '01' + @ClientNumber

    UPDATE [dbo].[APP_Clients]
    SET [ClientNumber] = @ClientNumber
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[APP_Clients] j ON i.ID = j.ID 

END
END
```

for table [dbo].[APP_Clients] with columns

```
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ClientName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[ClientNumber] [nchar](15) NULL,
[ClientGSM1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ClientGSM2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ClientEmail] [nchar](50) NULL,
[ClientOccupation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ClientWorkPlace] [nvarchar](100) NULL
```

after insert ClientNumber is not Updating.

With Regards,
Mohammed

Comment: Well, one way that your trigger is broken is that it assumes that it's only got to work for a single row. This isn't, generally, a safe assumption.

Comment: Thank you, so i need to execute this sql is to be done on stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the recursion level for triggers currently set on the DB.

If you do this:

```
SP_CONFIGURE 'nested_triggers',0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Or this:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
```

That trigger above won't be called again, and you would be safe (unless you get into some kind of deadlock; that could be possible but maybe I'm wrong).

Still, I **do not** think this is a good idea. A better option would be using an [INSTEAD OF trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288.aspx). That way you would avoid executing the first (manual) update over the DB. Only the one defined inside the trigger would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server (and Oracle) don't like you making changes to a mutating table within a trigger for that table. You either need to handle it a different way, or intercept the insert.

Since you are trying to alter the inserted data, you could use an `Instead of` rather than an `after` insert trigger:

Here is a very simplistic representation of how you would do it:

```
Create Trigger trg_App_Clients_Insert
On App_Clients
Instead of Insert
As
Begin
  Declare @no int;

  Select @no = IsNull(Max(ClientNumber), 0) + 1
  From App_Clients

  Insert into App_Clients (Name, ClientNumber)
  Select Name, @no
  From inserted
End
Go
```